# "Incomplete" Tricomi Hypergeometric Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, special-functions

I've come across this integral:

\begin{equation}
I(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_x^{\infty}t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-a-1}e^{-zt}dt
\end{equation}

a few times now, but I cant seem to get anywhere with it. I've called it the "Incomplete Tricomi Hypergeometric Function," since $I(0)=U(a,b;z)$, in analogy with the Incomplete Gamma Function.

Specifically, I'm looking at the case $I(1)$ near $z\rightarrow0^+$. Does anyone have any ideas? I've been stumped all day.

Comment: What conditions (if any) exist on $a,b$ and $z$. Do you hope for an elementary solution?

Comment: Almost certainty not. I was hoping that this could perhaps be recast in terms of common, well-studied special functions. The restrictions on $a$ and $b$ are $a\geq1$ and $b\geq0$. $z>0$ as well.

Comment: Actually, your answer on this question seems relevant: math.stackexchange.com/q/3265905/399922.

The only differences are the limits of integration and the nature of the binomial series expansion. In my case, $a=2n+1$ and $b=n$ for $n\geq0$, so $b-a-1=-n-2$, and the binomial series does not converge, since $1\leq y<\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $J(z) = \Gamma(a) I(1)$. If $b < 1$, the integral $J(0)$ converges and
$$\lim_{z \to 0^+} J(z) = J(0) =
\frac {{_2 F_1}(1 - b, 1 + a - b; 2 - b; -1)} {1 - b}.$$
If $b \geq 1$, subtract $t^{b - 2} e^{-z t}$ from the integrand and prove that the resulting integral is asymptotically smaller than $J(z)$. Then
$$J(z) \sim \int_1^\infty t^{b - 2} e^{-z t} dt =
z^{1 - b} \Gamma(b - 1, z) \sim
\cases {\Gamma(b - 1) z^{1 - b} & $b > 1$ \\ -\ln z & $b = 1$},
\quad z \to 0^+.$$
If the question is about getting the expansion for the case $b = n \in \mathbb N$ down to the $o(1)$ term, that can be done by taking the binomial expansion of $t^{n - 2} (1 + 1/t)^{n - a - 1}$ and repeating the process. We obtain
$$J(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2} c_k \Gamma(n - k - 1) z^{-n + k + 1} -
 c_{n - 1} (\gamma + \ln z) + \\
{_3 F_2}(1, 1, 1 + a; 2, n + 1; -1) c_n -
{_3 F_2}(1, 1, 2 - n; 2, 2 - a; -1) c_{n - 2} +
O(z), \\
c_k = \binom {n - a - 1} k,
\quad z \to 0^+.$$

Comment: How do you extract the finite bits?

Comment: If you mean the case $b \geq 1$, you can repeat the same procedure. If $b < 2$, then the integral of $t^{a - 1} (1 + t)^{b - a - 1} - t^{b - 2}$ exists. The constant term is that integral (which should have a closed form) plus the constant term from the expansion of $z^{1 -  b} \Gamma(b - 1, z)$.

Comment: In fact, if $b > 1$ and $b \not \in \mathbb N$, the constant term is always the same $J(0)$ from the case $b < 1$. Vaguely speaking, this is because there is a relation between finite part integrals and analytic continuation.

Comment: I'm looking specifically for the case $a=2n+1$ and $b=n$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer. I noticed that the $n=0$ case is fairly simple, but I'm not sure how to extract the exact divergent and finite parts for the $n>0$ cases. Is there any systematic way to go about this?

Comment: Why did you subtract $t^{b-2}e^{-zt}$ from the integrand?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: But how do you know what to subtract off? Also, isn't the $\mathcal{O}(z^{-1})$ term exactly one of the divergent bits we're looking for?

Comment: Compare the contributions from the integrals of $t^{b - 2} e^{-z t}$ and $t^{b - 3} e^{-z t}$. $O(z^{-1})$ was a typo.